# Spatial hashing for bounding box

Tags: c++, hash

I have a function that calculates spatial hash as follows:

```
int generateHash(int x, int y, int bucketWidth, int bucketsPerSide)
{
    return static_cast<int>(floor(x / bucketWidth) + floor(y / bucketWidth) * bucketsPerSide);
}
```

I have a bounding box defined as x,y,width,height and I'd like to retrieve all hashes for it. How can I do it? The problem seems trivial but I spent all day trying to figure it out and I just can't find a solution. It makes me feel hopeless.

Please note that the box can be so large that it will have more than 4 hashes (corners) assigned to it. I need to generate all hashes including the ones inside.

The dumb solution would be to start from x and y and increment both by 1 in a nested loop and add to std::set to ensure that each hash appear only once but this is extremely inefficient. I know there must be some better way to do it. I tried incrementing by bucketWidth but then it doesn't generate hashes for the rightmost side in some cases.

The closest I got is this:

```
std::vector<int> getOccupiedBucketIds(const cv::Rect& rect)
{
    std::vector<int> occupiedBucketIds;
    auto xIncrement = rect.width < bucketWidth  ? rect.width : bucketWidth ;
    auto yIncrement = rect.height < bucketWidth ? rect.height : bucketWidth ;

    for (auto x = rect.x; x <= rect.x + rect.width; x += xIncrement)
    {
        for (auto y = rect.y; y <= rect.y + rect.width; y += yIncrement)
        {
            occupiedBucketIds.push_back(generateHash(x, y, bucketWidth , cellsPerSide));
        }
    }
    return occupiedBucketIds;
}
```

This however leaves the following case unsolved when rect.width%bucketWidth > 0:
[image: unsolved case]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friends helped me solve it. Like I said, it was kind of trivial...

```
std::vector<int> getOccupiedBucketIds(const cv::Rect& rect)
{
    auto minBucketX = rect.x / bucketWidth;
    auto minBucketY = rect.y / bucketWidth;
    auto maxBucketX = (rect.x + rect.width) / bucketWidth;
    auto maxBucketY = (rect.y + rect.height) / bucketWidth;

    std::vector<int> occupiedBucketIds;
    occupiedBucketIds.reserve((maxBucketX - minBucketX + 1) * (maxBucketY - minBucketY + 1));
    for (auto y = minBucketY; y <= maxBucketY; y++)
    {
        for (auto x = minBucketX; x <= maxBucketX; x++)
        {
            occupiedBucketIds.push_back(y * cellsPerSide + x);
        }
    }
    return occupiedBucketIds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
std::vector<hash_t> hashes;
for(double yi=y+bucket_width/2;yi<ymax;yi+=bucket_width)
for(double xi=x+bucket_width/2;xi<xmax;xi+=bucket_width)
  hashes.push_back(generateHash(xi,yi,bucket_width,buckets_per_side));
```

You're not getting the rightmost edge because you are using floating-point mathematics. That is, when you are calculating numbers close to the edges of cells they may be slightly smaller, or slightly larger, than you would expect.

The solution is to instead calculate the locations of the centers of cells, which are far away from the edges.

Comment: What do you mean by xmax? rect.x+rect.width? Now it's not getting the leftmost corners.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to solve it using integer arithmetic simply by knowing hash values for each of the corners? I.e. difference between top left and top right hash is width expressed as number of occupied buckets. I don't know how to do that for height unfortunately.

Comment: @MaxWalczak: What do _you_ mean by `xmax`? Thankfully, you've added more content to your question since I provided the above answer, so I'm pretty confident that it should `rect.x+rect.width`. As regards the issue with the leftmost-corners, have you tried subtracting from the initial value, e.g. `yi=y-bucket_width/2`? It seems odd that the leftmost corners would be left out, since you are using a floor function.

Comment: yes. unfortunately this doesn't work either. It always generates one extra row and column to the left from x,y

Comment: @MaxWalczak: I'm not sure if integer arithmetic will work. You speak of a "hash" in your question, but hashes usually distributed their inputs randomly across a large range. If you mean to give buckets ordered numberings, perhaps it's better to speak of your function as generating a "grid index". If you are using a grid index, then you can use simple arithmetic, but you'll still need to account for floating point issues. There should be no reason why the height should need a significantly different calculation than the width.

Comment: @MaxWalczak: It's difficult to provide more help with the materials provided. The best thing I can say is that you _cannot_ treat the results of floating-point operations as though they are exact. Imagine each result as having a little band of uncertainty around it and adjust your code so as to avoid that band. If you want better answers, you'll probably have to make a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.